# Set focus on text input in angular template/route/form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, focus, angular-routing

I have the root page of my application which is a search page. I also have a div that slides in on the page when a button is clicked and within this area I have a favorites list. Everything inside this panel is angular.

The first screen of the panel is article when the url is "#/" and a second screen that contains an Add Favorites form is accessible by the angular route "#/newsearch". All of this works fine. Code is below.

How do I bring focus to a specific input in that Add Favorites form? So in other words when the angular route "#/newsearch" is navigated to, I want the input field with the name of "name" to be the field in focus so that they can just start typing the name of the favorite.

I have read some other stack overflow questions, but nothing stick out as an easy solution for my scenario.

**angular module:**
**/ng-modules/render-index.js**

```
angular
    .module("renderIndex", ["ngRoute","ngCookies"])
    .config(config)
    .controller("favoritesController", favoritesController)
    .controller("newFavoriteController", newFavoriteController);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "/ng-templates/favoritesView.html",
            controller: "favoritesController",
            controllerAs: "vm"
        })
        .when("/newsearch", {
            templateUrl: "/ng-templates/newFavoriteView.html",
            controller: "newFavoriteController",
            controllerAs: "vm"
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
};

function favoritesController($http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.searches = [];
    vm.isBusy = true;

    $http.get("/api/favorites")
        .success(function (result) {
            vm.searches = result;
        })
        .error(function () {
            alert('error/failed');
        })
        .then(function () {
            vm.isBusy = false;
        });
};

function newFavoriteController($http, $window, $cookies) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.newFavorite = {};
    vm.newFavorite.searchString = $cookies.currentSearch;
    vm.newFavorite.userId = $cookies.uId;
    vm.save = function () {
        $http.post("/api/favorites", vm.newFavorite)
            .success(function (result) {
                var newFavorite = result.data;
                //TODO: merge with existing topics
                alert("Thanks for your post");
            })
            .error(function () {
                alert("Your broken, go fix yourself!");
            })
            .then(function () {
                $window.location = "#/";
            });
    };

};
```

**angular view:**
**/ng-templates/favoritesView.js**

```
<div class="small-8 column"><h3>Favorites {{vm.favorites.length}}</h3></div>
<div class="small-4 column"><a class="tiny button radius" href="#/newsearch"><i class="fi-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add</a></div>
<div class="small-12 column">
    <div class="favContent">
        <div class="search row" data-ng-repeat="s in vm.searches">
            <div class="favName small-10 column"><span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" title="{{s.description}}"><a href="{{s.searchString}}">{{s.name}}</a></span></div>
            <div class="small-2 column"><i class="fi-trash"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**angular view:**
**/ng-templates/newFavoriteView.js**

```
<div class="small-8 column"><h3>Saving Search</h3></div>
<div class="small-12 column">
    <form name="newFavoriteForm" novalidate ng-submit="vm.save()">
        <input name="userId" type="hidden" ng-model="vm.newFavorite.userId" />
        <input name="searchString" type="hidden" ng-model="vm.newFavorite.searchString" />
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" ng-model="vm.newFavorite.name"/>
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="30" ng-model="vm.newFavorite.description"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="tiny button radius" value="Save" /> | <a href="#/" class="tiny button radius">Cancel</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know which input you need the focus on, you can just add this to one of them.

```
<input type="text" ... autofocus/>
```

If you need to change which one gets the focus depending on some other variable, then you may need to add a custom directive to your form that can look through the inputs on the form and then add the `autofocus` attribute.

Comment: Ok I thought I needed to write a directive and use it with my module. I guess as I get more requirements that might be something to look into.